# When using the JavaScript Class syntax, do classes set methods as a prototype by default?

Tags: javascript

I am learning about prototypal inheritance and I recently learned that if I use a factory function to create objects that all have methods, this results is unnecessary amounts of memory being used and that by setting the methods on the prototype, all objects generated from a factory function will share the same functions in memory. The same goes for a constructor function.

With that said, when I generated an object using the class syntax, the `method1` and `method2` methods by default are showing up in the prototype (`__proto__`) of the generated object. I was expecting to have to do manually like you would with a constructor function...

```
Test.prototype.get = somGetFunctionDefinedOutsideOfClass
```

in order to have the `method1` and `method2` methods set to the prototype.

Does this mean that if I generate 1 million objects all using the same Class, they all have their prototype set to the same methods and I wouldn't have to set the prototype manually?

```
const Test = class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        this.variable = 'testVariable'
    }
    method1() {
        console.log('method1')
    }
    method2() {
        console.log('method2')
    }
  } 

  const obj = new Test()
  console.log(obj)
  obj.method1() // logs: method1
```

Example using constructor function where methods are not on `__proto__`

```
  const Test = function TestObjectGenerator() {
    this.method1 = function() {
        console.log('method1')
    }
    this.method2 = function() {
        console.log('method2')
    }
  } 

  const obj = new Test()
  console.log(obj)
  obj.get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Classes are just syntactic sugar over a "functional object". ES6 class methods are set to the prototype automatically which means they behave no differently to ES5 function declaration objects.

Comment: I am totally with you on functions defined outside the Class but I'm still not understanding the `get` and `set` methods defined within the Class. They are both showing up in __proto__ so I am guessing that if I generated many objects from the Class, they'd all share the same prototype.

Comment: Yes they share the same prototype. ES6 classes are no different than regular ES5 function declared JavaScript classes. They behave in the exact same way. ES6 classes are simply a different syntax for creating regular ES5 JavaScript objects.

Comment: When I use a constructor function and do something like `this.get = function() {}`, the method shows up in the root of the object not `__proto__`, like it does when using a Class.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `get` and `set` are keywords to apply a specific set of operations on a member variable before it's retrieved / modified. Your example doesn't make much sense as you don't specify a member variable after your `get` and `set` declarations. As for typical method declarations in ES6 classes, they are set on the prototype of the object like normal ES5 function class declarations are.

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense. You're asking if you have to manually assign methods to the prototype when using ES6 syntax?

Comment: To answer you question, I am just trying to verify if when the class syntax is used, are methods declared inside the class syntax added to each instantiated objects prototype automatically? When using a constructor function, you'd have to set them manually.

Comment: Yes. If you're using an ES6 class, functions declared within the class are automatically set onto the prototype.

Comment: Think of ES6 classes as simply another way of creating ES5 classes. The end result is all the same. It's simply another way of creating classes (cleaner and more readable in my opinion). I also edited my answer containing the answer you were looking for if you wish to accept it.

Comment: I was using factory functions previously, which come with their own set of pros and cons. The biggest issue I have with them right now is performance. When generating large quantities of objects, 1 million, 10 million, factories are much slower. Typically 50% - 70%. I started with factories and avoided class/constructors when learning JS. Now I'm looking at them for reasons stated above.